Batch file - Root folder does not copy
1: The following code creates a date stamped destination folder correctly, ie:
\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\YYYMMDDHHNN\

2: However, only files from the source are copied over, not the folder. What I get is:
\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\YYYMMDDHHNN\Myfile01.txt
\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\YYYMMDDHHNN\Myfile02.txt

What I want to achieve is:
\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\YYYMMDDHHNN\MyFolderToCopy\Myfile01.txt
\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\YYYMMDDHHNN\MyFolderToCopy\Myfile02.txt

What am I doing wrong?
Note: I cannot specify the SOURCE as C:\Users\123456\ as there may be other folders in this path that I do not wish to copy.
Thanks in advance for any help!

SET SOURCE="C:\Users\123456\MyFolderToCopy\\"
SET DESTINATION="\\MyServer\MyFiles\Version\\"

REM - CREATE DATE STAMP FOR FOLDER:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
SET YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
SET MM=%dt:~4,2%
SET DD=%dt:~6,2%
SET HH=%dt:~8,2%
SET Min=%dt:~10,2%

SET STAMP=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%
SET NEW_FOLDER=%DESTINATION%%STAMP%
MKDIR %NEW_FOLDER%
XCOPY %SOURCE% %NEW_FOLDER% /E


To highlight code/data as shown, select the lines & press{}

At the beginning there's two backslashes in your Code for source so that could be omitted but maybe that's just a copy pasta mistake in this threat.
SET SOURCE="C:\Users\123456\MyFolderToCopy"

As for XCOPY try the additional /I switch:
XCOPY %SOURCE% %NEW_FOLDER%\MyFolderToCopy /E /I

This command ensures that the root folder MyFolderToCopy is also copied into the NEW_FOLDER. The /I switch forces XCOPY to treat the destination as a directory.
You can also use
pause

at the end, to see if there are any messages before the window closes.

Please don't do that, use Set "SOURCE=C:\Users\123456\MyFolderToCopy", along with %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SOURCE%" "%NEW_FOLDER%\MyFolderToCopy\" /E /I.

SET "SOURCE=C:\Users\123456\MyFolderToCopy\\"
FOR %%e IN ("%source%.") DO SET "NEW_FOLDER=c:\wherever\whatever\%%~nxe"

Notes: The double-\ is pointless
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax set var="value" is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.
Given you follow this advice,
SET "SOURCE=C:\Users\123456\MyFolderToCopy"

FOR %%e IN ("%source%\.") DO SET "NEW_FOLDER=c:\wherever\whatever\%%~nxe"

This means that the evaluated string is the parent of %source% which will have a last element of the parent directoryname. The last element is parsed as a filename, so %%~nxe picks up that part (see `for/? for documentation)
XCOPY %SOURCE% %NEW_FOLDER%\ /E

should create the directory - note the backslash following the destination
